# Как проверить разрешение на совершение звонков?

Tags: android

Написал такую проверку на разрешение, посмотрел другие решения, у них не было ошибки, а у меня permission помечается красным

```
private fun isCallPermissionGranted(): Boolean {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Как исправить путь Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE? Или вообще по-другому сейчас записывается проверка?

Comment: Наверное не тот манифест импортировали, должно быть `import android.Manifest`

Comment: ооо, спасибо большое